# Very strange error I got wrote the arrow table to the disk

Tags: r, arrow-functions, apache-arrow

I am learning the Apache Arrow for R and met the following issue.
My dataset has 85+ million rows what makes the utilizing of Arrow really useful.
I do the following very simple steps.

1. Open the existing dataset as arrow table

```
Sales_data <- open_dataset("Sales_Arrow", format = "csv")
Sales_data
```

The result is:

```
FileSystemDataset with 4 csv files
SBLOC: string
Cust-Loc: string
Cust-Item-Loc: string
SBPHYP: int64
SBINV: int64
Cust(Child)Entity: string
SBCUST: string
SBITEM: string
SBTYPE: string
Qty: double
SBPRIC: double
SBICST: double
Unit_Cost_Net: double
SBINDT: date32[day]
SASHIP: string
Entity: int64
ParentCustID: string
ParentCustName: string
Customer-ShipID-Loc: string
Pred_Entity_Loc: string
Cust(Child)-Entity: string
Item-Entity: string
```

Right after that I write the dataset to the disk as partitioned arrow data

```
write_dataset(Sales_data, "Sales All Partitioned", partitioning = c("Entity", "SBPHYP"))
```

and get the following **ERROR**

```
Error: Invalid: In CSV column #4: Row #444155: CSV conversion error to int64: invalid value '5e+06'
```

I checked the value in Sales_data[444155, 4]. It's absolutely the same as several previous and next rows.  **201901**

Please help me to understand what's going on and how to fix this issue

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be related to [ARROW-17241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-17241) which is caused by integers saved in scientific notation which is not recognized as int64 by the arrow csv reader.

The issue only pops up when writing the data because `open_dataset` is lazy so it only gets read when writing.

A workaround would be to pass a schema when opening or [casting the column to float 64](https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/r/defining-data-types.html#update-data-type-of-a-field-in-an-existing-arrow-table):

```
# Get the automatically inferred schema
csv_schema <- Sales_data$schema
# Change col 4 to float64()
csv_schema$SBPHYP <- float64()

# Cast to float64
Sales_data <- Sales_data$cast(target_schema = csv_schema)
```

You should then be able to cast back to int if you require it.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Is there any replacement for the ```slice``` function for ```arrow table```?

Comment: @grislepak arrow tables have a [slice method](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/r/reference/Table.html#r6-methods)